# Is there a maximum number of subprojects in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I had to add a new dynamic library to my Xcode workspace.

However, when I tried to build it, the new project was not build.

I already have 14 projects there, and this one is number 15.

I didn't have any issues before.

Is there a maximum number of libraries I can add to one workspace?

[EDIT]

I followed [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/231511/creating-a-project-inside-xcode), when I added this new subproject for the dylib, just like for any other 14 subprojects. So, there is no differences, from this POV.

[image: workspace]

[image: error]

Trying tofind the cause I did:

```
Igors-MacBook-Air:dbhandler igorkorot$ diff -bru libdialogs/libdialogs.xcodeproj/ libtabledataedit/libtabledataedit
Only in libdialogs/libdialogs.xcodeproj/: project.pbxproj
Only in libdialogs/libdialogs.xcodeproj/: xcuserdata
```

Are those `Build Generated`?

Comment: "*the new project was not build*" Can you elaborate on this? What errors are you seeing?

Comment: @esqew, no error, no output in the log panel, no indication during the build when the files are building, nothing...

Comment: @esqew, I also modified the OP - please check it. Thx.

Comment: @esqew, I also added screenshots of the `Workspace` and `error` I encounter.